# How to prevent middle mouse default in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm doing `@click.middle.stop.prevent="test"` but it doesn't prevent it from happening. It detects the middle mouse click and calls my function but I still get the default scroll wheel showing up.

Comment: I believe that this is implemented on the OS level rather than the browser - perhaps it works in this way for any other scrolling area ?

Comment: What vuejs version are you using? `.middle` mouse button modifiers only work with version 2.2.0+

Comment: I am using 2.6.10

Comment: I cant get `click.middle` or `mousedown.middle` working  either, in my case I have to add the `.native` modifier though.

Answer (score 0):

As of `vue v2.6.10`, `@click.middle` and `@mousedown.middle` do not override each other. That's why your `@click.middle.stop.prevent` does not work to override the default scroll wheel behavior triggered by `@mousedown.middle`.

You can fix that by either using `@mousedown.middle.prevent.stop="test"` or calling both `@click.middle` and `@mousedown.middle.prevent.stop` in the same element:

```
@click.middle="test"
@mousedown.middle.prevent.stop
```

Answer (score 0):

`@auxclick.stop` on the component will prevent middle click for it and will also stop it from propagating to parent.